# IPv6 tunnel multithreading in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, proxy, ipv6

My ISP does not support `IPv6` therefore I have only IPv4 address.
Lets say we have one account on http://tunnelbroker.net/ and one on http://www.sixxs.net/. Each of these resources provides tunnelling for IPv4 to IPv6 and, as far as I understand, on the output you get access to IPv6 networks and an IPv6 address, respectively.

The question is the following - I need an application with two threads, each of them will use its own tunneling options, such as Server IPv4 Address, Available DNS Resolvers etc. Obviously, threads have to work in parallel + bear in mind there might be more then two of them. Is it possible to somehow organize this without modifying global windows settings with netsh? Maybe there's a way to set tunnelling options for thread only, like it's done in `HttpWebRequest`:

```
HttpWebRequest.Proxy = new WebProxy(); //
```

Ok, so if we go to lower-level API, what do I need to do to put defaul HttpWebRequests/Responses inside such a tunnel (if I understand correctly, ofc)?

*EDITED

These are the the settings tunnelbroker.com advises to apply for default tunneling to work:

```
netsh interface teredo set state disabled
netsh interface ipv6 add v6v4tunnel IP6Tunnel my_ip_here server_ip_here
netsh interface ipv6 add address IP6Tunnel 2001:470:18:201::2
netsh interface ipv6 add route ::/0 IP6Tunnel 2001:470:18:201::1
```

I'm looking for any hints, actually, since am new to low level network programming.

Answer (score 1):

6to4 tunnels give your machine an actual IPv6 address. You can use multiple 6to4s, and you'll get multiple IPv6 addresses. To specify which one you want to use, you need to bind the socket to the IP you want.

Most higher-level APIs don't support setting the IP they bind to -- you're pretty well out of luck here, totally at the mercy of the dev of the API. Most APIs don't even try to bind to a specific address themselves, instead letting the OS handle the choice. It is a bit of an odd request, so it's hard to blame them :)

Comment: Is there a way to send HttpWebRequest through tunnel?